# Após Função Ajax, atualizar a página

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-core

Eu tenho esta função, e gostaria que se funcionasse tudo ok, gostaria que atualizasse a página, mas nem sempre ela atualiza, segue como estou fazendo:

```js
function GravarDados() {
    var dataInicio = $("#txtDataInicio").val();
    var dataFim = $("#txtDataFim").val();
    var diaVencimento = $("#txtDiaVencimento").val();
    var tolerancia = $("#txtTolerancia").val();
    var valor = $("#txtValor").val();
    var planoId = $("#cbplanos option:selected").val();
    var tipoPlano = $("#txtTipoPlano").val();
    var pessoaId = $("#id").val();
    var proporcional = $("#lblProporcional").val();
    var dataTolerancia = $("#txtDataTolerancia").val();
    var vencimentoC = $("#txtVencimentoC").val();
    var descricao = $("#cbplanos option:selected").text();
    var pre = $('#cbpre').prop('checked');
    var pos = $('#cbpos').prop('checked');
    var pro = $('#cbproporcional').prop('checked');
    var url = "/PessoasServicos/Gravar";

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , data: { DataInicio: dataInicio, DataFim: dataFim, DiaVencimento: diaVencimento, Tolerancia: tolerancia, Valor: valor, PlanoId: planoId, TipoPlano: tipoPlano, PessoaId: pessoaId, Descricao: descricao, Proporcional: proporcional, Pre: pre, Pos: pos, Pro: pro, DataTolerancia: dataTolerancia, VencimentoC: vencimentoC}
        , type: "POST"
        , datatype: "html"
        , success: function (data) {
            if (data.resultado > 0) {
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Eu chamo esta função aqui :

```js
 function closeModal() {
            GravarDados();
            $('#myModalPlanos').modal('hide');
            $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
            location.reload();
        }
```

E aqui é onde chamo a closeModal()

```html
<a href="#" onclick="closeModal();" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Gravar Item</a>
```

Já depurei várias vezes, e ele passa por todas as funções, sem erro, inclusive ele entra nesta, apenas não carrega os dados.

```html
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            PessoaVM = new PessoasViewModel
            {
                Pessoas = _context.Pessoas.Include(m => m.Classificacoes).SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id),
                ClassificacoesVM = _context.Classificacoes.ToList(),
                EstadoCivilVM = _context.EstadosCivies.ToList()

            };

            PessoasServicos = await _context.PessoasServicos
                .Include(m => m.PlanosServicos).Where(m => m.PessoaId == id)
                .ToListAsync();

            ContasReceber = await _context.ContasReceber
                .Include(c => c.Pessoas)
                .Include(c => c.PlanosServicos).Where(c => c.PessoaId == id)
                .ToListAsync();

            if (PessoaVM == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Page();
        }
```

Comment: Se "nem sempre" atualiza é porque deu erro. Verifique o console do browser.

Comment: Ele não retorna erro, eu já depurei e mesmo assim, vou colocar a função que ele entra quando carrega a página.

Comment: "nem sempre" atualiza porque você está aplicando a condição `data.resultado > 0` se o resultado for diferente não vai dar reload.

Comment: @marianac_costa `data.resultado > 0` é para verificar se a requisição foi bem sucedida?

Comment: Isso, eu já fiz o teste sem o data.resultado > 0, porém ocorre o mesmo problema, ele não atualiza, adicionei o código que ele percorre quando a página é carregada.

Comment: Verdade, deve ser o que disse o Leonardo. E também: seria mesmo caso de usar ajax, já que quer recarregar a página?

Comment: Ele não atualiza as duas tabelas que precisam ser atualizadas.

Comment: Já até tirei o data.resultado>0 para garantir que o problema não fosse ai, inclusive, depurando o código, ele entra na condição.

Comment: algumas vezes você tem que esperar o retorno da chamada do ajax  então no lugar de fazer o  if (data.resultado > 0) retorne o data e no final do da função use o }).done(function () ... para executar sua logica

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza horas funciona e horas não, já tirei até esse data.resultado > 0, eu faço a depuração funciona perfeitamente, sem nenhum problema, será que pode ser algo com o ASP.NET CORE?